# Finding a chordless cycle going through a vertex in a digraph

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs

Given a directed graph $G$ and one of its vertices $u$, is there a polynomial time algorithm answering the following question:

Is there a chordless cycle (induced cycle) of $G$ containing the vertex $u$?

---

There exists algorithms to enumerate all chordless cycles but they are not polynomial see (http://sma.uni.lu/bisdorff/ChordlessCircuits/documents/chordlessCircuits.pdf).
I could not find any web page or research article answering this question.

Note that the question consider a directed graph and all cycle have consistent orientation.

In undirected graphs, for any cycle $[u, v_0, ..., v_k]$ and a chord $\{v_i, v_j\}$, $[u, v_0, ..., v_i, ..., v_j, ..., v_k]$ is a "smaller" cycle containing, after repeating this process for all chords, the algorithm will end up with a chordless cycle of G contaning u.

This does not work anymore in directed graphs because of the orientation of the chords. I tried to solve it with a tunned *BREADTH FIRST SEARCH*. If it found a cycle, this cycle is chordless but it did not unsure that it would find a chordless cycle containing u if such a cycle existed. I tried to improve it so would always find it but then I think it beacame exponential.

Comment: So your cycles must have a consistent orientation? (That is, all the edges point in the same clockwise/anti-clockwise direction?)

Comment: Yes indeed, that is why the problem ocures

Comment: Do you care about the direction of the chord?

Comment: I must find a cycle which has no chord. 
The thing is, if you take a cycle and find a chord, if the chord has the same "orientation" than the cycle, then you can create an other "smaller" cycle that still contain the initial vertex.
But if the orientation of the chord is not the same as the orientation of the cycle, then you can create a "smaller" cycle but it does not contain the initial vertex

Answer (score 1):

I recently found an article answer my question :

Anna Lubiw: A note on odd/even cycles. Discrete Applied Mathematics 22(1): 87-92 (1988) https://doi.org/10.1016/0166-218X(88)90125-4

It appears that the problem is NP-complete and thus there is no polynomial time algorithm to answer my question unless P equals NP.

Comment: @Math_QED (and others) Without knowing how intricate the argument is, it feels misguided to me to request a summary/outline here. Observe that the answer refers to a peer-reviewed published paper in a reputable journal, so the concerns about link rot are also misplaced. More often than not math libraries will subscribe to this journal, so the interested viewers know what to do.